# How to use a pandas Styler function to color an html table by column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I'm rendering to an html table that I'd like to style using a gradient coloring based on a target value for each column.

Ideally, the target value would not have a background applied, and the other values would have shades of red or green depending on whether they were higher or lower than the target value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col 1': [7, 8, 12, 4, 'Target Val 1'],
                   'Col 2': [1, 4, 5, 8, 'Target Val 2'],
                   'Col 3': [7, 5, 3, 24, 'Target Val 3']})
```

I've tried to use `Styler.background_gradient` but I can only get that to use the largest value in the column as the high for the gradient and the target value ends up styled along with the rest of the column.

*Edit* Current code:

```
cm = sns.light_palette('green', as_cmap = True)

[t.style.set_table_attributes('border="1" class="dataframe table table-hover 
table-bordered"').background_gradient(cm).set_properties(**{'font-size': 
'12px', 'font-family':'Calibri', 'text-align':'center'}).format("{:.0f}%", 
subset=percent_cols).render() for t in style_teams]
```

Comment: Please post code for what you've tried so far

Comment: _Update_ It's not exactly what I was looking for but this gets me colors without a gradient based on the target value.

`.apply(lambda x: ['background-color:red' if v < x.iloc[-1] else 'background-color:green' for v in x], subset = percent_cols)`